# How to create dropdow widget when click on button?

Tags: flutter

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmVZz.png)

so how to create it? I tried to find out but still can't find a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a dropdown widget and wrap it with visibility widget which will be updated on the basis of that button click:

```
        bool visible=false;

        ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
          visible=!visible;    //onPressing the click button it will update visible variable
        }, child: Text('Click')),

        Visibility(
          visible: visible,    //which will make the dropdown visible
            child: DropdownButton(items: items, onChanged: (){}))
```

Comment: Does that widget overwrite the text? @Risheek Mittal

Comment: No it won't but you can make it change if you want to

Comment: It correct. Thanks you very much! ^^

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Visibility widget

```
bool isDropDownVisible = false

 Visibility(
 visible: isDropDownVisible,
 child: DropdownButton(
 // DropDown Code
 )
```

Now while onButtonClick set it as a below:

```
setState(() {
isCheckSelected =! isCheckSelected;
});
```